# Changing background color and keep parent image after hover

Tags: html, css

I want to change background color (from #333333 to #292929)  and keep parent image after making hover event on my list items, my problem is the color doesn't change it still always as before

this is my code :

### the part of my problem:

```
  .footer li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
    border-top: 1px solid #191919;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    display: block;
    background: #292929 url(http://s10.postimg.org/yejg5cted/widget_bg.jpg);
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100%
}
```

### All css code

```
   .footer {
    background: #333333 url(http://s10.postimg.org/yejg5cted/widget_bg.jpg);
    height: 318px;
}

.footer_container {
    width: 960px;
    height: 318px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Kozuka Gothic Pro;
    padding-top: 46px;
    color: #FFF;
}

ul.ul_links {
    width: 225px;
    height: 237px;
    margin-top: 19px;
}

ul.ul_links a {
    color: #cccccc;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 31px;
}

ul.ul_links a::before {
    content: url(http://s3.postimg.org/7bb9a1m4v/links.png);
    padding-right: 11px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

.footer li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
    border-top: 1px solid #191919;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    display: block;
    background: #292929 url(http://s10.postimg.org/yejg5cted/widget_bg.jpg);
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100%
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/py3uwpxn/9/)

intending results :

[image]

Comment: your image `http://s10.postimg.org/yejg5cted/widget_bg.jpg` is same color as your background, try to change that image or use only color,  `background: red;`

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question, but is that ? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/py3uwpxn/10/)

Comment: Because your background image covers the entire space so you can't see the background colour. And since the background image is the same as the footer's bg image, so you are not really seeing that much of a difference

Comment: in your case the color change but the image of background doesn't there i have changed the color like that  background: #903131 url(images/widget-bg.jpg)  but the color is not changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello there TH3 AWAK3NING, what you need to do is simply change the opacity of your background like so

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/py3uwpxn/11/

HTML

```
<div class="footer">
<div class="footer_container">
<div class="Links">
<ul class="ul_links">
<li ><a href="">www.example.com</a></li>
<li ><a href="">www.1stwebdesigner.com</a></li>
<li ><a href="">www.labzip.com</a></li>
<li ><a href="">www.labzip.com</a></li>
<li ><a href="">www.samplelink.com</a></li>
<li ><a href="">www.outgoinglink.com</a></li>
<li ><a href="">www.link.com</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.footer {
    background: #333333 url(http://s10.postimg.org/yejg5cted/widget_bg.jpg);
    height: 318px;
}

.footer_container {
    width: 960px;
    height: 318px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Kozuka Gothic Pro;
    padding-top: 46px;
    color: #FFF;
}

ul.ul_links {
    width: 225px;
    height: 237px;
    margin-top: 19px;
}

ul.ul_links a {
    color: #cccccc;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 31px;
}

ul.ul_links a::before {
    content: url(http://s3.postimg.org/7bb9a1m4v/links.png);
    padding-right: 11px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

.footer li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
    border-top: 1px solid #191919;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100%
}
```

Using the `background: rgba` it also allows you to tint the colour of the div which will look like you have changed the colour of the background :)

Comment: @TH3AWAK3NING no problem :)

Comment: can we use opacity instead of rgb ? because i don't know why you have made 0.2 in the last parametre if you are here can you give me some details and thank you again

Comment: If you use `opacity: 0.5;` the whole div will become transparent, the reason I am using `rgba` is for the background colour

Answer (score 1):

This will not be possible because the actual image is what defines the original color. What you would need to do in this case is create the image with a transparent background (so it only has the grid dots) then you would be able to change the background color behind it and see the effect you want.

---

Once you have your new image, set the following properties:

```
ul.ul_links a {
    background: #333333 url(http://s10.postimg.org/yejg5cted/widget_bg.jpg);
}

.footer li a:hover {
    background-color: #292929;
}
```

[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/5f2ajm8k/1/) that just needs the new transparent image to be added

Comment: no i want change the color of background but keeping the same image i will make screenshot of intending result

Comment: @TH3AWAK3NING: See my update, it is not possible unless you modify your image to have transparency

Comment: can you see the screenshot on the top please and tell me why in photoshop is diffrent and thank you so mush

Comment: @TH3AWAK3NING: I have answered the question, you need to change the background image source file to support transparency

Comment: so is not possible okey thank you for your answer (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the background image Url from `.footer li a:hover` and you are good.

```
.footer li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
    border-top: 1px solid #191919;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2); //Updated
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100%
}
```

Comment: in this case i will not have the same results of my screenshot on the top